# тег audio, конец аудиофайла

Tags: javascript, html

Делаю аудиоплеер, и появился в процессе вопрос. Как остледить конец песни, чтобы следом запустить другую?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть событие [`onended`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioScheduledSourceNode/onended)

```js
var aud = document.getElementById("myAudio");
aud.volume=0.5
aud.onended = function() {
  alert("Песня завершилась.");
};
```

```html
<audio id="myAudio" controls>
  <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/7/7a/Linkin_Park_A_Light_That_Never_Comes.ogg">
  Ваш браузер не поддерживается.
</audio>
```

Comment: @ВадимЯровой благодарность принято выражать [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)